# SQL server real field converts my numbers into normal format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I store some numbers in a 'real' type field.

I insert/read values to/from it from my c# application using ADO.net. When I query my data in Server Management Studio I can see it converts my numbers into scientific normal format, like: 2,211221E+07. I did not set anythig to do this, everything is default.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

MS SQL Server 2008 Express/.Net 4/VS2010

Comment: Can you give an example (what did 2,211221E+07 get inserted as originally)? Are you using REAL intentionally? (Usually DECIMAL/NUMERIC is a better choice, for various reasons.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't convert your reals (IEEE floating points) into scientific format: that's how it **displays** them in SSMS. Here's how ADO.Net maps data types between SQL Server and the .Net world: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx

For floating point types, SQL Server implements the ISO data type `float(`*n*`)`, where *n* is the size of the mantissa in bits (1-53 inclusive). `real` is a synonym for `float(24)`; `float` is a synonym for `float(53)`.

Rather as you might expect, floating point columns with a mantissa 1-24 bits in size are mapped to/from `System.Single`; whilst those with mantissa more than 24 bits in size are mapped to `System.Double`.

Sql Server's `money` and `smallmoney` data types really have little to do with money. They are  just fixed-precision decimals, with a precision of 4 decimal places (1/10000 of a unit). Ado.Net maps `money` and `smallmoney` to `System.Decimal` and maps `System.Decimal` to `money` (there is no mapping to `smallmoney`). This conversion suffers from something of an impedance mismatch, however, `System.Decimal` being a decimal floating point format. The conversion to/from SQL Server's `money` datatype can result in

- **Loss of precision.** If the `System.Decimal` value has more than 4 digits to the right of the decimal point, the extra digits are lost.
- **Gain of precision.** If the `System.Decimal value has less than 4 digits to the right of the decimal point, in the conversion to money, it gains precision in the form of extra digits (trialing zeros) to the right of the decimal point. That extra precision is maintained when it it read back from SQL Server.

Comment: Thx Nicholas. I used real numbers in SQL but haven't seen this behaviour. Now I understand it, thx so much.